# Which C/C++ header file defines a BYTE data type?

Tags: c++, c, windows

I'm porting a header with this declaration:

```
 struct tMaterialInfo {     
    char strName[255]; // the texture name
    char strFile [255]; // the texture
     BYTE color [3]; // the color of the object 
 };
```

The header has the following includes:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <gl\gl.h> // Header File For The OpenGL32 Library
#include<gl\glu.h>// Header File For The GLu32 Library
#include <gl\glaux.h>
```

Where does that BYTE come from?

Comment: +1 for clearly stating the question, as well as providing enough context to provide a useful answer.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I'm guessing it's from [Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383751(VS.85).aspx).

> A byte (8 bits).
>
> This type is declared in WinDef.h as follows:
>
> typedef unsigned char BYTE;

Comment: And one should add that it shouldn't be used. All of the all-caps integer/string types are useless code-uglification that serve only to make code unnecessarily tied to Windows. Simply use the corresponding standard types like `unsigned char` or `uint8_t` (which must be identical if the latter exists at all).

Comment: stdint was not not added to Visual Studio until 2010.

Comment: If you are using WINAPI functions you should be using Windows datatypes. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vcgeneral/thread/c066968d-8cb7-4e5a-9807-aa9cd47c65ed

Comment: The definition is (*meanwhile?*) located in minwindef.h, which is included by windef.h. And windef.h is included by Windows.h. ... Unfortunately they don't use a define like `_BYTE_DEFINED` in wtypes.h for Win16 types or `BASETYPES` in minwindef.h for `ULONG`, `USHORT` and `UCHAR`.

Answer (score 11):

If you are programming C for Windows I assume you are using **Visual Studio** to develop. You can **right click** on any keyword and select **Go To Definition** <kbd>F12</kbd> to find where it is defined.

BYTE is defined in WinDef.h

```
typedef unsigned char       BYTE;
```

Comment: Even with available debug info (and loaded symbols for kernel32.dll & ntdll.dll) my VS 2022 just brings me a selection of 4 locations with suitable definitions, incl. a typedef from `WTypesbase.h` within a `#if 0`

Answer (score 5):

Almost certainly from one of the many headers included from `windows.h`. The Windows SDK has included `typedef`s for `BYTE`, `WORD`, and `DWORD` since at least Windows 2.0 days (the earliest Windows SDK I recall having).