# BYTE as undeclared identifier even though I have included windows.h

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, console-application

My code is as follows

```
// ConsoleApplication1.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//
#include <windows.h>
#include "stdafx.h"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    BYTE* pAlloc1 = NULL;
    return 0;
}
```

creating following errors.

> error C2065: 'BYTE' : undeclared identifier

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which C/C++ header file defines a BYTE data type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4486140/which-c-c-header-file-defines-a-byte-data-type)

Comment: tl;dr It's from `WinDef.h`

Comment: @Cyber This is not a duplicate.  Including `windows.h` should already include `WinDef.h`.

Comment: @Cyber, But the proper way to include `WinDef.h` is by including `Windows.h`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have `#include "stdafx.h"`, which usually means that you're using a precompiled header.  If you use a precompiled header, anything preceding the precompiled header will be discarded.

Try reordering your `#include` lines so that `"stdafx.h"` is first. (Or change `stdafx.h` to `#include <windows.h>`, which is generally where you want to put commonly-used system headers.)