# Can´t get the avisynth+ filtersdk lib to compile (C++)

Tags: c++, avisynth

How to get the avisynth+ library to work in c++? I am using Visual Studio 2017.

I have tried including the avisynth.h file from the avisynth+ git repo. Also including the avisynth+ git repo folder as a include and defined *AMD64* and it wont compile

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <avisynth.h>


int main()
{
    IScriptEnvironment *env = CreateScriptEnvironment(2);

    return 0;
}
```

I get several

> third operand to the conditional operator ?: is of type 'void', but
>   the second operand is neither a throw-expression nor of type 'void'
>
> expression must have arithmetic or unscoped enum type

errors in `avisynth.h` when i try to compile it

Comment: Might be faster to ask in `#avs-plus` channel on IRC rizon network, if it's still alive.

Comment: I don't know if it's related to your problem (likely not), but [any `#include`s before `#include "pch.h"` is likely to be wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24900128/179715).