# How to overload [] with two different return types

Tags: c++

Assume a bytes buffer on the heap:

```
BYTE *Buffer = new BYTE[128] ;
```

Sometimes I need a BYTE:

```
BYTE x = Buffer[5] ;
```

Sometimes I need a pointer to part of the buffer, e.g. to map a structure against:

```
MyStruct *Str = (MyStruct*)&Buffer[5] ;
```

If I want to mimic this in a class:

```
class MyBuffer
{
public:

MyBuffer()  { Buffer = new BYTE[128] ; }
~MyBuffer() { delete[] Buffer ; }

BYTE operator[](int Index) const { return Buffer[Index] ; }
// BYTE *operator[](int Index) const { return &Buffer[Index] ; }

BYTE *Buffer ;
};
```

Situation 1. would work, but not 2.

```
MyBuffer Buffer ;

BYTE x = Buffer[5] ; // Works

MyStruct *Str = (MyStruct*)&Buffer[5] ; // Won't work
```

I can't implement two variants of the same operator that only differ in return type.
So I wonder, is what I ask possible ?

Comment: Return a reference.

Comment: in case you ever actually need to "overload based on return type" you can return a proxy that can be converted to either of the two different types. Its not really overloading based on return type but as close as you can get

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just change the return type to be a **reference type**(*lvalue ref to be particular*) as shown below. **This works because** a function call like `f()` where `f` returns by lvalue-reference is an lvalue and we can apply `operator&` to an lvlue.

```
class MyBuffer
{
    //--v------------------------->return by reference
    BYTE& operator[](int Index) const 
    { 
        return Buffer[Index] ; 
    }

//other code as before
};
MyStruct *Str = (MyStruct*)&Buffer[5] ; // compiles now
```

Also refer to [What is Strict aliasing rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule) in case you're wondering about dereferencing the returned pointer.

Comment: It would be undefined behavior to use the resulting pointer without `std::launder`.

Comment: @JanSchultke Yes, I think we should leave a comment to [Strict aliasing rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule) so that OP will be aware of this or rather I will add this link to the answer directly at the end.

Comment: @user12002570: Does strict aliasing matter here? [`BYTE` is a typedef for `unsigned char`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4486140/364696), and [`char*` (along with its explicitly signed/unsigned counterparts) isn't subject to the strict aliasing rule](https://stackoverflow.com/a/99010/364696). As long as `MyStruct` can be legally used without explicit construction, and isn't otherwise violating [the rules for accessing new objects through an old one](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.life#8), I think this is okay (I'll admit to not fully understanding `std::launder`).

Comment: @ShadowRanger the problem is that pointer provenance leads back to a `BYTE[128]` array. Converting a `BYTE*` within that to `MyStruct*` means you have a pointer with provenance of the wrong type. The compiler can assume that `MyStruct*` does not really point to a `MyStruct` object, even if one was previously placed in the byte array with `std::construct_at` or placement new. Prior to C++17, this would have been fine since the pointer automatically points to the object if there is one. Since C++17, you need `std::launder` as a provenance fence to tell the compiler to mind its own business.

Comment: @JanSchultke: Gotcha, thanks for the clarification (I didn't realize the standard had changed in a way that made `std::launder` *necessary* in cases that used to work without it, I thought it was mostly just closing a gap in the preexisting standard). Like I said, I don't fully understand `std::launder`. :-)